# Is there a way to know what triggered the beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, html, django, onbeforeunload

I have a page on my Django app with a form. I would like to alert users if they try to exit the page without submitting their form. I implemented this with the `beforeunload` method, written below:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

However, this also raises an alert when a user submits a page.

Is there a way to identify which event is triggering the `beforeunload` (either submit or exiting, refreshing,etc.)?

Comment: @C Regnew  Please try this inside the form submit script:
 window.onbeforeunload = null;

Comment: Can the script be inline (in the input tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag to determine whether the form has been submitted or not, and based on that flag, you can decide whether to show the `beforeunload` prompt.

Here's a way to do this:

1. Set a flag `formSubmitted` to determine if the form has been submitted.
2. Add an event listener to your form's submit event to change the value of the flag.
3. In the `beforeunload` event listener, check the value of the flag. If the form hasn't been submitted, show the alert; otherwise, let the page unload.

Here's an example of how you might implement this:

```js
let formSubmitted = false;

// Assuming your form has an id "myForm"
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    formSubmitted = true;
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // If the form hasn't been submitted, show the alert
    if (!formSubmitted) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = 'You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
});
```

Now, when you submit the form, the `formSubmitted` flag will be set to `true` and the `beforeunload` event will not trigger the alert. But if you try to navigate away, refresh the page, or close the tab without submitting, the alert will be shown.

Remember to make sure that you have a mechanism to reset the `formSubmitted` flag if needed (for example, after an unsuccessful form submission or if you allow the user to edit the form after submitting it).